# How to do unix export in windows eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unix

In Unix we can set variable like below:

```
$ export FOO="bar"
```

How can i do samething in windows through eclipse, i need to set this variable before my app starts.

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 1):

### Environment Variables

1. Go to `Run` -> `Run Configurations`
2. Select your configuration on the left.
3. Click the `Environment` tab.
4. Click `New...`
5. Enter your variable.

### Program Arguments

1. Go to `Run` -> `Run Configurations`
2. Select your configuration on the left.
3. Click the `Arguments` tab.
4. Enter your argument into the `program arguments` box.

Comment: `-DFOO='bar'` is not the same as `export FOO="bar"`, the former is a program argument, the latter is an environment variable. Try setting the program argument `-DFOO='bar'`

Comment: When i set as program arguement ,it is treating as file and getting  java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\workspace\test\-DFOO=bar

Comment: I am passing xml files to  ac = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args); So spring thinks that .-DFOO='bar' is a file. How to skip this arg to pass.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is FOO and what uses FOO? Your code or a library?

Comment: I am passing xml files to ac = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args); So spring thinks that .-DFOO='bar' is a file. I removed this .-DFOO='bar' and paased to spring.But still this not set .-DFOO='bar' .is there anyway to set in java code it self? I tried to set the variable using  System.setProperty.

Comment: What part of your application requires FOO to be set to BAR?